# MsgBox doesnt work with multiple strings

Tags: .net, vb.net

When i use this code:

```
Dim sessionid = "sessionid = " + """" + TextBox2.Text + """"
Dim steamlogin = "steamLogin = " + """" + TextBox3.Text + """"
Dim steamparental = "steamparental = " + """" + """"
Dim sortextera = "sort = " + """" + """"
MsgBox(SettingsDir, sessionid + steamlogin + steamparental + sortextera, True)
```

Visual Basics comes up with an error saying it can't convert this to a string.
Any help?

Comment: Have you set `OPTION STRICT` to `On` or `Off`? Also, use `&` in VB.NET if you concatenate strings because `&` is defined exclusively for strings as opposed to `+` and reduces your chances of generating an unintended conversion..

Comment: What is the SettingsDir variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MsgBox` expects a [`MsgBoxStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) as the second parameter, not a string. So this should work:

```
MsgBox(SettingsDir, MsgBoxStyle.Information, sessionid + steamlogin + steamparental + sortextera)
```

(i also don't know the purpose for the boolean as last parameter)

I also prefer:

- using `MessageBox.Show` instead of the VB6 `MsgBox` to be .NET compatible
- using `&` instead of `+` for string concatenation because `&` is defined exclusively for strings as opposed to `+` and reduces your chances of generating an unintended conversion
- using `String.Format` to format strings:

  ```
  Dim message = String.Format("sessionid = ""{0}"" steamLogin = ""{1}"" steamparental = ""{2}"" sort = ""{3}""",
                              TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, "", "")
  ```

Comment: Thanks! You fixed it :)